# repeated measures ranking data

Tags: repeated-measures, ranking

I have a repeated measures design where  180 participants rank their preferences for 12 items at time1, and then undergo an intervention, and then they rank their preferences for the same 12 items again at time2. The 12 items are split between 2 factors, e.g, there are 12 foods, 6 are junk food, 6 are healthy.

I am trying to come up with a test that would show whether or not the intervention changes the rankings based on the factor, more specifically, if the participants ranked junk food more highly than healthy food in the first ranking, but then rated healthy food more highly than junk food after the intervention.

Ideally I'd like to show an interaction such that junk > healthy at time1 and healthy < junk at time2.

A paired samples ttest or a repeated measures anova doesnt seem appropriate given that the ranking data is not independent. Any suggestions for analyses or papers that could help?

---

I am supplying another example to better illustrate the concept. Suppose I have the hypotheses that all people prefer coffee to tea, but believe their mothers prefer tea to coffee. One way I could do this is to have people rate their preferences for 6 kinds of coffee and 6 kinds of tea, then supply ratings for what they believe their mothers' preferences are. All ratings would be done independently so in this case I would run a 2: beverage type(average rating for coffee, average rating for tea) x 2: rating for whom (self, mother) repeated measures ANOVA and show that people have a preference for coffee but expect their mothers to have a preference for tea.

Now imagine, instead of ratings I asked people to rank order their preferences for the 6 teas and 6 coffees all in one question, then on the next screen I asked them to rank order their mothers preferences. Is there an analysis for raNKing data that is analogous to the repeated measures ANOVA for raTing data?

Comment: Did your experiments have any controls (a randomly selected group that was given a different intervention for comparison)? If not, then you might not want to work too hard on this, because even if you detect pre-post differences you won't be able to draw any supportable conclusions about the effect of the intervention.

Comment: there were three groups total: one which experienced no intervention, so presumably their rankings should remain consistent (but question still stands to be able to test that). a second condition where the manipulation should go the opposite direction, increase preference for junk. and a third condition where the manipulation should increase preference for healthy.

Comment: That clarification added, this question need not depend on a specific intervention. Imagine you were asked to rank your preferences for difference kinds of coffee and different kinds of teas on tuesday and then rank those same items on thursday? Or rank your preferences for coffee and teas and your mothers preferences for coffees and teas. The question is essentially about seeing if ranking x items under some set of conditions is is different than ranking those same x items under different conditions.

Comment: The appropriate analysis depends on the nature of the experiment. In this case you will need to compare pre-post differences among types of intervention. Merely observing a pre-post difference within any single group is meaningless. (There is no assurance I, or anybody else in your non-intervention group, should give consistent evaluations from one day to the next. Maybe our evaluations depend on weather or the latest news, etc.)

Comment: I appreciate the feedback whuber--Please see a clarification of my question above.